# angular-rails-templates (templates are caching, but ng-include not working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using the angular-rails-templates plugin to preload html files in the assets/javascript/templates (sprocket fix is not working)

When I use the inspector, I can see that the CacheTemplate is being triggered:

```
// Angular Rails Template // source: app/assets/javascripts/templates/bannertime.html angular.module("templates").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) { $templateCache.put("bannertime.html", '<section id="landing-page-banner">') }]);
```

My app.js

```
app = angular.module('logged_out', ['templates', 'ng'])

app.controller "logged_out", ($scope) ->
    $scope.banana = "hello banana face"
```

My index.html.erb

```
<div ng-app="logged_out" ng-controller="logged_out">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ng-include="bannertime.html"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please explain to me why ng-include is impossible to make work? I've been working on this for 3 days now.

Answer (score 2):

Damn you world!

ng-include requires two different quotes ?!?!?!?!

```
Once I changed <div ng-include="bannertime.html"> to <div ng-include=" 'bannertime.html' "> everything worked.
```

Goddddd damnt